# The Apple App Store web site shows a "Preview" page for the TuneIn Radio app, but no such app is found in App Store?

Tags: macos, mac, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, monterey

The Apple App Store web site (for United States) shows a page for this app:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tunein-radio-music-sports/id418987775

> TuneIn Radio: Music & Sports
>
> MLB, News, Local FM Stations
>
> TuneIn

See screen shot:

[image: screenshot of web page for Apple App Store Preview]

Yet any search for any of these terms within the App Store app on my Mac never shows this app. The search results show many other apps, but not the one whose name is "TuneIn" and whose publisher is "TuneIn".

I do have the filters set for iOS apps, not Mac apps, as this app is not published for the Mac according to that mysterious *App Store Preview* page. See screenshot.

[image: screenshot of searching in Apple App Store app on macOS]

As a workaround, is it possible to search the App Store for a particular publisher rather than for a particular app?

Comment: What country store are you using?

Comment: @mmmmmm United States.

Comment: Most likely the developer decided to not make the iOS app available on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal  as far as I can see. Since I used El Captain back in the day there was always two stores- the Mac Store for Mac Apps and the mobile store for Apps that run in iPhone and iPad.  I can remember searching for iPhone apps and not finding them on my Mac unless I used Google ( use Duck Duck Go now ). I asked at the Genius desk and they said it was normal and I should use the device to search for the app I wanted to use it on.

Comment: However things have changed - if you are on an Apple Silicon machine you can run some iPad apps The App Store mac app does show these iPad apps.

Comment: @mmmmmm Did it change for the apps. I thought iPhone apps had to be fixed somehow to run on Mac

Comment: By default iPad apps will start to run on macOS Apple Silicon they might not fully work in some cases. The developer can mark the app in the AppStore so that they can't be run on a mac but they have to take that action.

Comment: I guess that’s my point   The developer has to make it available on both stores.

Comment: No I think it is that apps are on both stores by default. The developer has to do something to remove it from the Mac app store - this is just from experience of apps I use. Several work in the iPad but work noticeably worse on the Mac

Comment: Either way, the developers have to do something. Maybe turn it off for the other store because they don’t want it there

Comment: No that is the point - they would have the app in both stores if they did nothing.

Comment: How do you know what the intentions of the programmer is.